# Problem with MERN app on netlify and heroku (CORS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, netlify

This my first question but I completely have noo idea what to do :/ I learn javascript technologies. I've written my MERN app where I handle login and register feature. My backend is deployed on heroku but client side is deployed on netlify. Everything is working fine locally, but when I test my app after deployment to heroku and netlify, everything is ok till I try send a request to my backend (for example during login process). My request is pending aproximately 20-30 sec and after this time I receive annoucement with this content - "***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pokemontrainer-app.herokuapp.com/auth/signin' from origin 'https://pokemon-trainer-mern-app.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***". I've been looking for a solution. Most often I saw infos about _redirects file for client build folder for netlify. Unfortunately documentation is very short and unclear when it comes to this issue. Maybe one of you had a similar problem and resolved it with success? If _redirects file is really solution, can I ask for short ifnormation how I should prepare it?

this is my backend code:

server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose =  require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mainRoutes = require('./routes/main.js');
const signinSignupRoutes = require('./routes/signInSignUp.js');
const userTrainersRoutes = require('./routes/userTrainers.js');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

console.log(process.env.FRONTEND_URI);

//------Express-------

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '500mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '500mb', extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(cors(
  {
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'https://pokemon-trainer-mern-app.netlify.app'
  })
);

app.use('/', mainRoutes);
app.use('/auth',  signinSignupRoutes);
app.use('/loggedUser', userTrainersRoutes);

//------Mongoose-------

const main = async() => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.USERS_USERNAME}:${process.env.USERS_API_KEY}@pokemon-app.2s1cy.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`);
    console.log('Database connection works!')
  }catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}

main()
.then(()=> app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server works on port ${port}`);
}))
.catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

signIn&Up.js file:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Joi = require('joi');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const {User, validation} = require('../models/user.js');

const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(404).json(err.message);
  }
}

const signUp = async(req, res) => {
  
  try{
    const {error} = validation(req.body);
    error && res.status(400).send({message: error.details[0].message});
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(user) {
      res.status(409).send({message: 'User with this email already exists.'})
    } else {
      if(req.body.userName === "") {
        res.status(400).send({message: `Username field is empty`});
      } else if(req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword || req.body.password === "") {
        res.status(400).send({message: `Passwords aren't the same or password field is empty`});
      } else {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12);
        await User.create({email: req.body.email, userName: req.body.userName, password: hashedPassword});
        res.status(201).send({message: 'User registered succesfully!'});
      }
    }
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send({message: 'Internal server error :('});
  }
}

const signIn = async(req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://pokemon-trainer-mern-app.netlify.app');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  
  try{
    const {error} = signInValidation(req.body);
    error && res.status(400).send({message: error.details[0].message});
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    !user && res.status(401).send({message: 'User with this email adress is not registered :('});
    const validatedPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validatedPassword && res.status(401).send({message: 'Incorrect password :('});
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken(user._id, user.email);
    res.cookie('token', token, {
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
      secure: false,
    }).status(200).send({message: 'Log in succesfully', userData: {userId:user._id, userName: user.userName, email: user.email, trainers: user.trainers, logged: true}});
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}

const signInViaGoogle = async(req, res) => {
  
  try{
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    !user && res.status(401).send({message:'You have to register your account with this email in this app'});
    const token = user.generateAuthToken(user._id, user.email);
    res.cookie('token', token, {
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === `${production}` ? true : false,
      secure: false,
    }).status(200).send({message: 'Log in succesfully', userData: {userId:user._id, userName: user.userName,email: user.email, trainers: user.trainers, logged: true}});
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send({message: 'Internal server error :('});
  }
}

const logout = async(req, res) => {
  
  try {
    const {token} = req.cookies;
    token && res.clearCookie('token').send({message: 'Cookie cleared'});
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send({message: 'Internal server error :('});
  }
}

const newSession = async(req, res) => {
  
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  !token ? res.status(200).send({cookie: false, logged: false}) : res.status(200).send({cookie: true, logged: true});
}

// validation for signIn

const signInValidation = (data) => {
  const JoiSchema = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().required().label('E-mail'),
    password: Joi.string().required().label('Password'),
  });
  return JoiSchema.validate(data);
}

module.exports = {getUsers, signUp, signIn, signInViaGoogle, logout, newSession}
```

client side code:

apiHandling.js file:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { loginNativeUser, updateUserData, newSession } from '../actions/userActions.js'

const url = 'https://pokemontrainer-app.herokuapp.com';

const instance =  axios.create({
    baseUrl: url,
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
})

export const newSess = async (dispatch) => {
   await instance.get(`${url}/auth/newSession`)
   .then(res => {
       dispatch(newSession(res.data));
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
}

export const signInByGoogle = async (userData, setError, history, dispatch) => {
    await instance.post(`${url}/auth/signin/google`, {
        email: userData.email,
    })
    .then(res => {
        setError(null);
        dispatch(loginNativeUser(res.data.userData));
        history.push('/');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        setError(err.response.data.message);
        history.push('/auth/signin');
        alert(err.response.data.message);
    })
}

export const signIn = async (formData, setError, history, dispatch) => {
    await instance.post(`${url}/auth/signin`, {
        password: formData.password,
        email: formData.email,
    })
    .then(res => { 
        setError(null);
        dispatch(loginNativeUser(res.data.userData));
        history.push('/');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        setError(err.response.data.message);
        history.push('/auth/signin');
        alert(err.response.data.message);
    });
}

export const signUp = async (formData, setError, history) => {
    await instance.post(`${url}/auth/signup`, {
        userName: formData.userName,
        password: formData.password,
        confirmPassword: formData.confirmPassword,
        email: formData.email,
    })
    .then(res => { 
        setError(null);
        history.push('/');
        alert('Registered succesfully')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        setError(err.response.data.message);
        history.push('/auth/signup');
        alert(err.response.data.message);
    });
}

export const cookieClear = async () => {
    await instance.get(`${url}/auth/deleteCookie`)
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Cookie cleared');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data.message);
    });
}

export const addTrainer = async (userId, trainer) => {
    await instance.patch(`${url}/loggedUser/${userId}/addTrainer`, {
        userId: userId,
        trainer: trainer
    })
    .then(res => {
        alert('Trainer added');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        alert(err.response.data.message);
    });
}

export const removeTrainer = async (userId, trainerId) => {
    await instance.patch(`${url}/loggedUser/${userId}/${trainerId}/removeTrainer`, {
        userId: userId,
        trainerId: trainerId
    })
    .then(res => {
        alert(res.data.message);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        alert(err.response.data.message);
    })
}

export const addPokemon = async(userId, trainerId, pokemon) => {
    await instance.patch(`${url}/loggedUser/${userId}/${trainerId}/${pokemon}/addPokemon`, {
        userId: userId,
        trainerId: trainerId,
        pokemon: pokemon
    })
    .then(res => {
        alert('Pokemon caught');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.response.data.message);
    })
}

export const updateData = async (userId, dispatch) => {
    await instance.post(`${url}/loggedUser/${userId}/updateData`, {
        userId: userId,
    })
    .then(res => {
        dispatch(updateUserData(res.data.userData));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data.message);
    });
}
```

If it is needed, I can also send a github link with code.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Try removing the `res.setHeader` in the signIn conteoller.

Comment: I've tried deploy my backend without res.setHeader etc. Still the same problem :/

Comment: 1. You can host your backend and front end code both at Heroku, this will sort out your issue
2. You can try installing the Moesif cors changer extension, then switch it on at you front end

Answer (score 1):

You can add a middleware into you express app.
I happened to write some cors config for my express api today.
For your reference (server side code):

```js
const corsMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  res = applyCorsHeaders(res);
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end()
    return
  }
  next()
}

const applyCorsHeaders = res => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  // or res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
  )
  return res;
}
```

Then use this middleware in your app:

```js
app.use(corsMiddleware);
```

For more about CORS, here's one official intro: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all responses. I decided to put my whole app on heroku. It works. CORS policy problem disappeared. Problem was related to different domains (heroku for backend and netlify for frontend). I decided to use this solution because I have never tried to put frontend on heroku. It required a rearrangement of my project folder. Now my project structure is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNuLP.png)

1. Go to Heroku.com
2. Click on your "Dashboard"
3. Click "New"
4. Click "Create New App"

- Give the app a name and click "Create App"

5. in server.js file add:

```js
const path = require("path");
    
    //
    
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
    
    //
    
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
    
    // remember - in heroku app set a port like this - 
       const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

6. in client package.json file add "proxy":

```js
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000" - or other url of your server
```

7. set up enviroment variables in heroku app:

Go to "Settings"
Click "Reveal Config Vars"
Add a new variable and click "Add".

8. add next script in package.json in root folder:

```js
"scripts": {
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm 
         run build"
    }
```

9. in Procfile folder:

```js
 web: node server.js
```

10. in root folder
    heroku git:remote -a app-name-from-heroku
    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m "commit name"
    git push heroku main (or master)

You app should works. I found this clear solution in coursework.vschool.io (article title - Deploying MERN App to Heroku (using your Git Master Branch & MongoDB Atlas).